# Why is my search string not found in a larger string if compared with Regular Expression?

Tags: swift, regex, swift-string

I am trying to find a substring in another string. I am using Regular expressions. The code is as below:

```
let occurrence = "Kingfisher:"
let string = "Swiss: SW123123\nKingfisher: KF994455\nQuantus: QS12343\nJetAir: FF7865667\nThai:  TH123442\nDelta: D123FGR\nAmerican: AME9879567\nGoAir: GO345682\nCathey: CATH020234\n        "
if let range = string.range(of: "\\b\(occurrence)\\b", options: .regularExpression) {
    print(range)
} else {
    print(occurrence, "not found.")
}
```

Why is my substring "Kingfisher:" not getting found.

Comment: `:` is not a word char. `:\b` only matches the `:` that is followed with a letter/digit/`_`. Use `"(?<!\\w)\(occurrence)(?!\\w)"` or  `"(?<!\\S)\(occurrence)(?!\\S)"`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew just to clarify my doubt are you saying in this case ":" which is a non word character is followed by " " which is also a non word character and hence the search fails?

Comment: Since `:` is followed with a space, another non-word char, there is no match, right. `\b` meaining is context dependent.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew in the "(?<!\\w)\(occurrence)(?!\\w)",  the "(?!\\w)" is no use right because the assertion for that group happens after occurence has matched and that assertion wont affect the search. Is "(?<!\\w)\(occurrence)[\s\W]" more suitable for my case ?. I ask for more clarification because this lookahead and lookbehind is a bit complex for me to grasp.

Comment: I guess `(?<!\w)occurrence(?!\S)` is a better bet if you need a right-hand whitespace boundary

Comment: True but then it will fail for cases where the characters after the occurence non word.

Comment: (?<!\\w)(occurrence)[\s\W] is better fit here I guess.

Comment: `\W` matches what `\s` matches. I told you need `(?<!\w)occurrence(?!\w)`. Use it.

Comment: As per this https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#negative-lookahead    But isnt the negative lookahead after occurence is matched not going to affect the search as it will just assert for the patterns after it and not before it? Or does the assert affect the result of matching before it as well